# SQL query create stored procedure error 'Incorrect syntax'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I use sql to create the stored procedures , but I get an error " Incorrect syntax near ' = ' "
And here is my code

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp_T_CATEGORY_GetByTop]
@top nvarchar(10),
@where nvarchar(200),
@order nvarchar(200)
AS
    DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(500)
    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT TOP ('+@top+') * FROM [T_CATEGORY]'
    IF LEN(@top) = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM T_CATEGORY'
        END
    IF LEN(@where) > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE' + @where
        END
    IF LEN(@order) > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'ORDER BY' + @order
        END
        EXEC(@SQL)
```

thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

You need `space` before and after `where` and `order by`

```
IF LEN(@where) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE ' + @where
    END
IF LEN(@order) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ORDER BY ' + @order
    END
```